# How do you call a function that has asynchronous code in a function that does not support concurrency?

Tags: swift, async-await

I have a service that fetches some data for me called:

```swift
func filter(filter: String) async {
    if filter == "soccer" {
        Task {
            annotations = try await soccerService.getAnnotations()
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the error whenever I call this function inside of a view builder:

> 'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency

Error:

```
Button {
    filter(filter: "soccer") // error here
} label: {
    Text("Soccer")
}.buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle())
```

How do I fix this?

I've tried wrapping things in a `Task { }` and a `do { } catch { }`, but still no luck.

Comment: Post the code that actually gives you an error.

Comment: `ViewBuilder`s aren't asynchronous. Also, it doesn't make sense in SwiftUI to call a function in a `ViewBuilder` that isn't returning a `View`. Perhaps you want to call this in `task` or `onChange`, etc?

Comment: I've edited the code snippet that has the error. How exactly would I want to call this on `Task` because the function would change on a different button that the user presses?

Comment: You don’t need the async keyword on that function the way it is.

Comment: yup, that does it. Removing the `async` makes the code compile and work the way that it should. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function as written does not need the keyword.

```
func filter(filter: String) {
    if filter == "soccer" {
        Task {
            annotations = try await soccerService.getAnnotations()
        }
    } 
}
```